# How to export Alembic in selection sequence or batch with Python script

Tags: python, scripting, export, alembic

Currently, I would like to automate some Alembic export tasks, by creating a script. How can I do this?

I know this script (but not sure how to make it happen):

```
bpy.ops.wm.alembic_export(filepath="Drive/Path/object.abc", 
                          selected=True, 
                          renderable_only=False,
                          visible_layers_only=False, 
                          flatten=False, 
                          uvs=True, 
                          packuv=True,  
                          normals=True, 
                          vcolors=False, 
                          face_sets=True, 
                          subdiv_schema=False, 
                          apply_subdiv=False, 
                          global_scale=1, 
                          triangulate=False,
                          quad_method='SHORTEST_DIAGONAL',
                          ngon_method='BEAUTY', 
                          export_hair=False, 
                          export_particles=False)
```

There are more options.

How do I make Blender export Alembic by script on one selection, then another selection after I've exported that?

Comment: what is it you dont know how to do? You posted a script that will export the selected object to an alembic file. Please [edit] your question and add exactly what it is that you can't do.

Comment: I am getting crashes with that script, and I am not sure how to either batch export or sequentially export different selection sets. Do objects need to have an active selected to export?